# Is it possible to overwrite the value of UIUserInterfaceStyle at any given point?

Tags: ios, react-native, uiuserinterfacestyle

I'm working on a react-native app on which I want to detect how many people have dark mode and how many people have light mode but I want to keep light mode as `UIUserInterfaceStyle`.

So since I'm just detecting I tried a couple of solutions but the above problem statement is not being satisfied.

*The project was created using CLI and not expo.*

I tried using `useColorScheme`

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, Appearance } from 'react-native';
// ... other code and imports

<Text>Mode is: {Appearance.getColorScheme()}</Text>
//... other code
```

The above works as it'll give me `light` or `dark` as expected. But if I set `UIUserInterfaceStyle` to `Light` in `Info.plist` it always gives `light` and I'm unable to detect if user's phone is in dark mode or light.

I found that there is `[overrideUserInterfaceStyle][1]` which is provided for iOS by Apple so it's swift based.

Basically, I know the ways around which means to create two themes, detect which mode is on, and launch the light theme always. I'm looking for a different solution, is it's **possible to override the value of `UIUserInterfaceStyle` from react-native ios?**
OR
**Is there a way I can change the `Appearance` of a specific screen?** For example, if the user has a dark mode, I detect that in react-native and override the appearance from `dark` to light for that specific screen.

[1] https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/3238087-overrideuserinterfacestyle

Comment: you can create a custom native module which does this part right?

Comment: Creating a bridging might work but I was looking for a simplified solution. Is there a way I can change `Appearance` for a specific screen? For example, if the user has a dark mode, I detect that in react-native and override the appearance from `dark` to light for that specific screen.

Comment: not sure , i guess creating a bridge will be a much cleaner way